# Can gluten cause depression?

Tags: medical-science, nutrition, depression

Yesterday, I read a really serious testimony of someone saying that, since they stopped eating gluten, they aren't depressed anymore.

I did some digging and find several articles linking gluten to depression. Like [this one](https://universityhealthnews.com/daily/depression/the-surprising-link-between-gluten-and-depression/) or [this French one](https://www.thierrysouccar.com/blog/le-gluten-du-ble-moderne-rend-depressif).

The source of this last article is:

> Peters, S. L., Biesiekierski, J. R., Yelland, G. W., Muir, J. G. and Gibson, P. R. (2014), Randomised clinical trial: gluten may cause depression in subjects with non-coeliac gluten sensitivity – an exploratory randomised clinical study. Alimentary Pharmacology & Therapeutics. doi: 10.1111/apt.12730.

Is this study trustworthy? Were similar studies later done to refute or confirm it?

Comment: Standard disclaimer when talking about depression -- even *if* avoiding gluten can help *some* people with *their* depression, it does not follow that *all* people with depression can "cure" *their* depression by avoiding gluten. And note that going around and telling someone who *is* depressive to "just try a gluten-free diet, why don't you" can be **actively harmful** (as many other well-intentioned but ill-advised suggestions).

Comment: @Rsf Psychiatrists. And friends who are on an (unrelated) gluten-free diet but *also* suffering from depression.

Comment: @Rsf Also, people who know the exact cause and trigger for their depression, which has nothing to do with diet. And *please* take that advice from my first comment. This is *not* an area where armchair advice can do *any* good. We're not talking occasional sadness here, but an affliction that is driving people into despair for most of their lifes. Research and investigate all you want, but *do not* inflict theories and well-meant amateur advice on the actually afflicted that are struggling to get through yet another day. That is not helpful.

Comment: @DecSolar Just wanted to let you know that, as someone with depression, I absolutly agree with what you said. Thank you for takong the time to post that and I hope more people will realize that "armchair advices" are definitively not good *and* not helping

Comment: Related: [Are gut bacteria a cause of depression?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/41700/)

Answer (score 8):

**Gluten-free diet and depression in individuals with NON-CELIAC GLUTEN SENSITIVITY**

[Non-celiac gluten sensitivity](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6182669/) refers to intestinal and other symptoms related to the ingestion of gluten in the absence of celiac disease and wheat allergy.

[The article from the question](https://universityhealthnews.com/daily/depression/the-surprising-link-between-gluten-and-depression/) mentions few studies in which gluten-free diet was associated with less depression in individuals with non-celiac gluten sensitivity. 
Such association was also observed in one [2018 systematic review](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6266949/):

> ...gluten-free diet (GFD) significantly improved pooled depressive
>   symptom scores in GFD-treated patients...There was a tendency towards worsening symptoms for non-coeliac gluten
>   sensitive patients during a blinded gluten challenge vs. placebo.

**Gluten-free diet and depression in individuals with CELIAC DISEASE**

Gluten-free diet may not necessary reduce depression in those with celiac disease:

> In patients on gluten‐free diet, in fact, fatigue tends to be reduced
>   in intensity while depression seems to persist or even worsen,
>   supporting recent observations that *gluten‐free diet alone fails to
>   significantly reduce the percentage of CD [celiac disease] patients
>   affected by depression.* *([Aliment Pharmacol Ther., 2005](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/j.1365-2036.2005.02619.x))*

In celiac disease, depression may not be related directly to the disease pathology:

> In coeliac disease, affective disorders should be ascribed to
>   difficulties in adjusting to the chronic nature of the disease rather
>   than directly to the disease itself...*([Eur J Gastroenterol Hepatol.,
>   2003](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/14624151))*

**Diet and depression in GENERAL POPULATION**

Six recent systematic reviews about the effect of various diets on depression ([2013-1](https://academic.oup.com/ajcn/article/99/1/181/4577292/), [2013-2](https://bmcpsychiatry.biomedcentral.com/track/pdf/10.1186/1471-244X-13-175), [2019-1](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6755986/), [2019-2](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0261561418325408), [2019-3](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0261561418325408), [2019-4](http://www.ijpvmjournal.net/article.asp?issn=2008-7802;year=2019;volume=10;issue=1;spage=42;epage=42;aulast=Khanna)) do not even mention gluten.

**In conclusion,** there is some evidence about the association between gluten-free diet and reduced depression in some individuals with non-celiac gluten sensitivity but not in others.